# PHP: use declared variable with data from MySQL inside an included file

Tags: php, mysql

htmlfile.php contais all the HTML
phpfile.php contains all the PHP and includes htmlfile.php
MySQL table called BOOKS has the columns: ID and TITLE
phpfile.php works like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli(server, user, password, db);

include "htmlfile.php";

//Here i store my titles from the table inside an array
$sql = "SELECT TITLE FROM BOOKS";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $titles[] = $row['TITLE'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

In my included htmlfile.php i want to use an element of the array inside a paragraph:

```
<body>
<p><?php echo $titles[2]; ?></p>
</body>
```

When i start the phpfile.php in my browser, the paragraph is empty.
So i thought about switching the places like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli(server, user, password, db);

$sql = "SELECT TITLE FROM BOOKS";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $titles[] = $row['TITLE'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

include "htmlfile.php";
```

But now most of the content in my HTML isn`t even showing up on the site. It looks completely messed up. I already tried to connect the database with my htmlfile.php but it didn't  change anything. The array itself works correctly when i echo in phpfile.php
So how can i do this?

Comment: Just assign it like any other variable? `$book_1_title = $row["TITLE"];`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to store. One title, or all of them? The method you use will depend on what you will do with the result and how long you need to store it for. ADyson has already illustrated one method, but is it what you need?

Comment: If you're only fetching one book, there's no need for a `while` loop.

Comment: @ADyson i already tried this. My main goal is to use this variable in HTML like this:  
 <p><?php echo $book_1_title ?></p>
But my site keeps the paragraph empty, when i reload it.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular yes i want to store this TITLE only. Should be quite simple.  I tried it the same way, ADyson showed, but it doesn`t seem to work yet. My goal is, to echo it inside a paragraph tag

Comment: See the answer below which should show you how to do things. If you're still having a problem after reading that, you should update your question to include a full example of exactly what you're trying, then we can check if there is some mistake in what you've written.

Comment: `most of the content in my HTML isn't even showing up on the site. It looks completely messed up` ...so you're saying there's actually more HTML in htmlfile.php than you've shown us? And that's what's not working? But what does "all messed up" actually mean? Have you examined the resultant HTML source in your browser's developer tools to see where it's gone astray?Can you share more of the HTML with us - we can't understand the problem just from the brief snippet. It's hard to see why moving the `require` to the other side of that bit of PHP could cause issues, so I think we still lack context

Comment: @ADyson Honestly thank you for your help, I think i learnt alot about correctly writing questions and searching for mistakes in my code :D I went through my HTML over and over again as there wasn't shown any error and found a line that somehow blocked my page. What should i do with my question now. It won't help any people in the future, should i just delete it?

Comment: Either you just delete it, or you update it to contain a [mre] of the issue, and then answer it yourself with the solution, if you think it could be beneficial to others with a similar issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer - you're encouraged to answer your own questions :-). Glad you solved it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is already stored in a variable. It's stored an an element in the `$row` array. If you want to output it in a paragraph element you can do this:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<p>' , $row["TITLE"] , '</p>';
    }
```

If you want to store the element for use later you can do this (but this won't work well if you retrieve more than one title):

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $book_1_title = $row['TITLE'];
    }
    echo '<p>' , $book_1_title , '</p>';
```

If you're storing several titles you might do this:

```
    $titles = []; // Create an array
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $titles[] = $row['TITLE'];
    }
```

Note that the `while` loop will terminate when `fetch_assoc()` returns false. With a loop structured like that `$row` will contain `false` after the loop terminates, and your title(s) won't be available from there.

If your intention is to retrieve exactly one title then you don't need  a `while` loop at all.

There's more than one way to do things, and your choices will be guided by what else you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem seems to be my HTML. I was already wondering about the fact, that i can't store a simple value. 
My Problem appears to be, that i have my HTML in an own File, which is included in my PHP File, but the HTML doesn't show my Title when i do `<p> <?php echo $book_1_title ?></p>` inside the included HTML File. The problem is, that i have to declare the Variable before including my HTML File but if i put my whole if..while.. before including it, the outcome is completely messsed up and most content of my HTML doesn't even show up.

Comment: @ano that's all pretty vague to be honest...it would be better if, as I suggested above, you update your question to provide a [mre] of the issue showing actual code, then we can identify precisely where the problem is. We can't really suggest fixes based on descriptions, because it doesn't provide us with enough precision about what the specific issue is.